# installing reactive-banana-wx

Tags: haskell, cabal, reactive-banana

when you try to install the library reactie-banana-wx, get the error:

```
src\CRUD.hs:10:18: Could not find module `Data.Map': It is a member of the hidden package `containers-0.4.0.0'. Perhaps you need to add `containers' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
```

installed the command:

```
cabal install reactive-banana-wx
```

Please help correct the problem.

Comment: have you tried to install the containers package in a similar way (cabal install containers)?

Comment: @Carsten König: you don't want to do that: `containers` is a boot library of GHC and thus shouldn't be manually upgraded/built.

Answer (score 4):

The advice it offers is sound, if a bit confusing: `cabal install` hides the step where it produces the `.cabal` file! Here's how you can do that part explicitly:

```
cabal unpack reactive-banana-wx
cd reactive-banana-wx-*
gvim *.cabal # or whatever editor you prefer
# follow the instructions given in the error
cabal install
```

Comment: And don't forget to contact the maintainer so it can be fixed in the next version :)

Comment: What do you mean by "hides the step where it produces the `.cabal' file"?  The file is part of the tarball!

Comment: @ivanm Personally, I use `cabal install` exactly _because_ it hides everything from me! This includes figuring out the right URL to visit to get the tarball, getting the tarball, unpacking it, checking its dependencies and doing this process recursively for any missing ones, configuring it, building it, putting the built library in the right place, telling GHC about the new library... it really does a lot for us. I think it's perfectly fair to call all the things it does "hiding".

Comment: @Daniel Wagner: oh, by "produce" I thought you meant by it *generating* the .cabal file.